# Is there a way to output an equation include equal sign with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

with sympy

```
A = Matrix([[1,1],[2,2],[0,0]])
MatMul(A.T, A, evaluate=False)
```

I can output an equation like this

[image]

is there a way to output an equation containing an equal sign like this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following should work. `Eq` is an `Equality` container that prints with an `=` separating the left and rhs.

```
>>> pprint(Eq(MatMul(A.T, A, evaluate=False), A.T*A))
```

You can also get the latex representation of the same by replacing `pprint` with `latex`.

Answer (score 0):

For ipython users (and vscode with `#%%` separators) this will produce a nice graphical display.
The `evaluate=False` in the Eq prevents evaluation and reduction of the result to True or False..

```
display(Eq(MatMul(A.T, A, evaluate=False), A.T*A, evaluate=False))
```

Another useful variant is to display the variable name like so:

```
display(Eq(S('A'),A, evaluate=False))
```